# Dancing Cell in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets, the first pulls the data from the second to print out later.

I have three scripts on the first sheet. Print, Edit Update.

Print works flawlessly.

Edit works flawlessly.

Update is where my issue is.

When I update the form, four cells dance, their data changes without me making any changes on the sheet.

The first two are B17 and B20.

The second are Q23 and R25.

The problem is that the jumping of data is between all four cells. the Sales Order may jump to Part Revision, and the Part ID jumps to Sales order, and sometimes Sales Order jumps to NCMR Qty.

I can't figure out why this is happening. The VBA code looks solid, can someone not only verify this is going on in their computer, but perhaps why it is happening?

Here is the sheet:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/Edit%26Update.xlsm

Here is the code that is causing the problem.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub PENCMR()
        Dim i As Integer

        'Internal NCMR
        Dim wsPE As Worksheet
        Dim wsNDA As Worksheet
        Dim c As Variant 'Copy Ranges
        Dim P As Range 'Paste Ranges

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        'Setting Sheet
        Set wsPE = Sheets("NCMR Output")
        Set P = wsPE.Range("A63:V63")

        Set wsNDA = Sheets("NCMR Data")

        c = Array("AG6", "B11", "B14", "B17", "B20", , "Q23", "B23", "Q11", "Q14", "Q17", "Q20", "Q26", "V23" _
            , "V25", "V27", "B32", "B40", "B46", "B52", "D58", "L58", "V58")

        For i = LBound(c) To UBound(c)
            P(i + 1).Value = wsPE.Range(c(i)).Value
        Next

        With wsNDA
            Dim NR As Long, LR As Long, LC As Long
            Dim f As Range

            LR = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            LC = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            NR = LR + 1

            Set f = .Range("A3:A" & LR).Find(what:=P.Cells(1).Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                f.Resize(1, P.Cells.Count).Value = P.Value
            Else
                MsgBox "The data can't be shown, please review the data in question, if no problem can be found please contact the developer"
            End If
        End With
        Range("A63:V63").ClearContents

        With wsPE
            .Range("B11").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,2,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("B14").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,3,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("B17").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,4,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("B20").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,5,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("B23").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,7,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("Q11").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,8,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("Q14").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,9,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("Q17").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,10,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("Q20").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,11,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("Q23").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,6,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("R26").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,12,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("V23").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,13,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("V25").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,14,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("V27").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,15,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("B32").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,16,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("B40").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,17,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("B46").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,18,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("B52").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,19,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("D58").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,20,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("L58").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,21,FALSE),"""")"
            .Range("V58").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AG$6,'NCMR Data'!$A$2:$Y$999999,22,FALSE),"""")"
        End With

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

I am now getting an error here.

```
P(i + 1).Value = wsPE.Range(c(i)).Value
```

Comment: hey Matt, did you make any attempt to step through your code line by line to see when the cells start changing arbitrarily. I can't see the sheet, because my office is blocking the site.

Comment: Yup, I actually was working on a spreadsheet chart to verify that the numbers, and the cells were all where they were meant to be. As far as I can tell when it updates it moves things over to the right after the 2nd cell, but and I do stress this but, except those four cells, everything else is exactly where it is meant to be. But if you look at the code, as far as I can tell it doesn't do that.

Comment: Try with a DOT before `Range("B11").Formula` and similarly for others in `With wsPE` so that they become `.Range("B11").Formula`

Comment: Ok, trying now. Is there a reason why this makes a difference? I'm just curious....

Comment: I am checking the file. If you don't use DOTS then the formulas will get updated in range of the active sheet and not of `wsPE`. Give me few minutes while I check your file and see what you mean by "Dancing Cells" :)

Comment: Ok, and I just did what you suggested, and still the cells dance... I've also updated the script above.

Comment: I checked the file but the code you posted above do not match with the code in the module... Am I missing something?

Comment: When i run the above updated code, I get the message `The data can't be shown, please review the data in question, if no problem can be found please contact the developer`

Comment: I haven't updated that file yet, but I think I figured out the issue. As for you getting that, I don't know why you are except that I put that in there just in case there was a catastrophic failure. I'll update in a sec.

Comment: Ok, new error, both the script and sheet have been updated.

Comment: There errors occurs because you have a blank space in arrray C at the 5th element... "AG6", "B11", "B14", "B17", "B20", , "Q23",...  kill that and it will work. I just did and it ran through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error occurs because you have a blank space in array C at the 5th element.

```
"AG6", "B11", "B14", "B17", "B20", , "Q23",
```

Get rid of that and it will work. I just did and ran it flawlessly.

Comment: I figured that out this morning, I was kicking myself it the butt after realizing it. Thanks :)

Comment: If have had many, many moments like that! Glad you got it going.